# `Brolgar` facet_sample function example confusing error?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get this error in my own code and when I run the documentation example for `facet_sample()` (shown below) using the `brolgar` package on its own built in "heights" data. Nothing I've Googled is similar, and appreciate any guidance on what is causing this, and have included SystemInfo below in case it may be caused by something in my installation.

```r
library(brolgar)
#> Warning: package 'brolgar' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(heights,
       aes(x = year,
           y = height_cm,
           group = country)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_sample()
#> Error in f(...): 3 arguments passed to .Internal(is.unsorted) which requires 2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United States.1252
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2021-12-19
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package        * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  anytime          0.3.9   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  assertthat       0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  brolgar        * 0.1.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  cli              3.1.0   2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  colorspace       2.0-2   2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  crayon           1.4.2   2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  curl             4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  DBI              1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  digest           0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  distributional   0.2.2   2021-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dplyr            1.0.7   2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ellipsis         0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  evaluate         0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fabletools       0.3.2   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fansi            0.5.0   2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  farver           2.1.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fastmap          1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fs               1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  generics         0.1.1   2021-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  ggplot2        * 3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  glue             1.5.1   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gtable           0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  highr            0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  htmltools        0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  httr             1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  knitr            1.37    2021-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lifecycle        1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lubridate        1.8.0   2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magrittr         2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  mime             0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  munsell          0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pillar           1.6.4   2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  pkgconfig        2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  purrr            0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R6               2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  Rcpp             1.0.7   2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  reprex           2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rlang            0.4.12  2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rmarkdown        2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  rstudioapi       0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  scales           1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  sessioninfo      1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringi          1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringr          1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble           3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyr            1.1.4   2021-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyselect       1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tsibble          1.1.1   2021-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  utf8             1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  vctrs            0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr            2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  xfun             0.28    2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xml2             1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  yaml             2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Users/dlucey/OneDrive - South Bronx Classical Charter School/Documents/R/R-4.1.1/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your code run just fine for me.  Maybe restart the R session?

Comment: Tried with fresh session and making sure nothing but Brolgar and ggplot2, but no luck, but thanks for trying.